# Is there a closed formula which is true for precisely one of $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x^3$.

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let $\mathcal L^=$ be a first-order language with equality, with a single one-place function symbol $f$.  Let $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ be two $\mathcal L^=$-structures both with domain equal to $\Bbb N$.  Further let $\mathcal A$ interpret the symbol $f$ as the function $f^{\mathcal A}(x)=x^2$ and $f^{\mathcal B}(x)=x^3$.

Is there a closed $\mathcal L^=$ formula which is true for precisely one of these structures?  Decide this without using quantifier elimination.

---

I am almost certain that these are not isomorphic and therefore I cannot prove, in this way, that the structures are elementarily equivalent.

However, I also can't think of a formula which distinguishes them.  They both have precisely two fixed points of the function: $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ in both settings.  We can't talk about between-ness to help out.  We can't name any specific numbers or arithmetic operations other than the one given by $f$.

I can't think of how I would apply Los-Vaught since I can't think of a theory which I could show to be complete.  I suppose I could try to write down formulas that seem to say everything I can think of about $f$, like "there are precisely two fixed points, and for all other numbers, they do not map to these fixed points".  But that just doesn't seem like it would be complete, or if it is, I wouldn't know how to show it.

I don't think Lowenheim-Skolem would help because they're both already countable structures.

I strongly suspect that there is no closed formula distinguishing them, but I'm out of ideas about how to prove it.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I think they are isomorphic. An $\mathcal L^=$-structure is essentially a directed graph on vertex set $\Bbb N$ with exactly one outgoing edge from each element (from $x$ to $f(x)$). Both structures consist of two fixed points, no other cycles, and infinitely many disjoint infinite chains.

Comment: @Karl Interesting point -- but when I actually try to write down the isomorphism I keep finding the map always missing a point in the image.  For instance, of course $0\mapsto 0$ and $1\mapsto 1$.  It makes sense to me that, if it can be done, it can be done with $2\mapsto 2, 3\mapsto 3$, and so on, mapping things to themself if they're not in the image of $x^2$.  Now in order to have the homomorphism property we would need $4\mapsto 8$ and so on.  But then nothing would ever map to 4 and I don't think anything could while maintaining the homomorphism property.

Comment: After thinking about your comment more I wondered if maybe I could just take any element I wanted, which is not in the image of $x^2$, and map it over to 4.  But then eventually (i.e. after enough powers of whatever element that is) I think this should "interact with the powers of 2" in some way that would break the homomorphism, no?

Comment: The way I was thinking about it, you can pick any bijection from the set of non-squares to the set of non-cubes. Then the rest of the isomorphism is determined, e.g. if we map $x\mapsto y$ then we map $x^2\mapsto y^3, (x^2)^2\mapsto(y^3)^3$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, indeed one can build an isomorphism. I didn't realize this because I thought any mapping from the nonsquare 2, for example, and the nonsquare 8, would have some kind of bad interactions -- but what I was forgetting is that although 8 comes up as an eventual power of 2, that doesn't matter because we're mapping these to cubes and so the interaction that I was worried about doesn't occur.

Anyway, the more complete answer goes a little like this: Define $g$ to be any bijection from the non-squares to the non-cubes.  Then extend $g$ to a function $h:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ by defining $h(x)=g(x)$ on any non-square $x$, and $h(x^2) = [g(x)]^3$ for everything else.